# Get runtime dependencies in cmake for windows executables and install them

Tags: windows, cmake

I use CMake for windows and need to pack the required dll files with the executable because that executable is a windows service and needs all of them in the same folder. The code below uses the new GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES feature but I need to install these runtime dependencies too. The code below does not add the dll files to the package. A simple copy of the files works fine. Is there any solution to pack all required dll files within the installable package?

```
if(WIN32)   
    target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME}_obj 
        PUBLIC
            WINDOWS
    )
    
    install(CODE [[
        file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES 
            DIRECTORIES 
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw32\\bin"
                "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
            PRE_EXCLUDE_REGEXES 
                "api-ms-*" 
            POST_EXCLUDE_REGEXES
                ".*system32/.*\\.dll"
            RESOLVED_DEPENDENCIES_VAR deps 
            EXECUTABLES $<TARGET_FILE:myapp>)
        message(STATUS ${deps})
        file(INSTALL DESTINATION "bin" TYPE EXECUTABLE FILES ${deps})
    ]])
endif()
```

Comment: Are the shared libraries you're using part of your cmake project, or are they external libraries?

Comment: These are external libraries from msys2 and other third party locations.

Comment: `GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES` returned the correct list because you can use it with a copy command instead of install command?  So the problem is with you install command and not `file(GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES)`.  You could make this clearer by posting the output status message and list `${deps}` and the log file of what gets installed during the install step.

Comment: Since CMake 3.21, there is [`install(RUNTIME_DEPENDENCY_SET)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#install-imported-runtime-artifacts), which may be of use here.